# I am trying to calculate a factorial using recursion method, so I wanna know if this part of code is correct for recursion

Tags: c, function, for-loop, recursion, factorial

I am a beginner programmer, and I am trying to do create factorial function using recursion method. I have looked at many solutions, and then I've tried to brainstorm another solution, which why I am posting here. So, is my recursion method approach correct?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(unsigned int i);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Fact: %d", factorial(5));
}

int factorial(unsigned int i)
{
    int j;
    int TotalFact;

     /* Termination Condition */
     if(i <= 1)
     {
        return 1;
     }

     /* Body, Recursive Expansion */
     for(j=1; j<i; j++)
         {
            TotalFact=i * factorial(j);
         }
     return TotalFact;
}
```

**Edit:**
I do not want to use`i * factorial(i - 1)`.

Comment: The loop is pointless, you're ignoring every result but the last. Just return `i * factorial(i - 1)`.

Comment: Add a statement like `printf( "%u\n", i);` to the beginning of the function to trace how many times the function executes... How many times do you expect it to execute?

Comment: you are missing the point of recursion. Dont loop, just call yourself with a modified set of arguments

Comment: If you don't want to do `i * factorial(i - 1)`, then you don't want to do recursion. So you need to make up your mind. Are you computing the factorial using recursion, or are you computing the factorial using a loop? Either one works, but you can't do both at the same time.

Comment: I don't see why the function argument needs to be `unsigned` when **13!** will overflow a 32-bit `int` anyway.

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense at all. Choose if you want to loop or do recursion.

Comment: "I do not want to do `i * factorial(i - 1)`" - but that is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a `for` loop inside of your recursion, just return `i * factorial(i - 1)`. Here is your code with some minor changes.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial(unsigned int i);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Fact: %d", factorial(5));
}

int factorial(unsigned int i)
{
     if(i <= 1)
     {
        return 1;
     }
     else
     {
        return i * factorial(i - 1);
     }
}
```

As @Fe023 has pointed out, this could also be solved using a ternary operator.

```
int factorial(unsigned int i)
{
     return i <= 1 ? 1 : i * factorial(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes it is, but I wanted to make a code that would be the most beginner-friendly. I could've used a ternary operator in return statement.

Comment: Change `i * factorial(i)` in the main text to reflect reality. It's not an infinite recursion.

Comment: @pmacfarlane what are you talking about? Do you mean `i * factorial(j)` in the question? If so, I don't think we should be editing the code OP has posted.

Comment: I copied `i * factorial(i)` from your answer. Take a look.